# Is there a way to join tables by multiple columns?

Tags: ormlite-servicestack

I can join by a single property

```
var sql = new JoinSqlBuilder<ClassA, ClassB>().Join<ClassA, ClassB>(src => src.PropA, dst =>  dst.PropA);
```

I don't see a way to join by multiple properties though. Pretty sure there's no way to do that yet, but want to double-check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The join class in joinbuilder only has one class/column name, so it seems pretty certain there is no way using default join builder.

```
class Join
{
    public Type Class1Type { get; set; }
    public Type Class2Type { get; set; }
    public Type RefType { get; set; }
    public JoinType JoinType { get; set; }
    public string Class1Schema { get; set; }
    public string Class2Schema { get; set; }
    public string Class1TableName { get; set; }
    public string Class2TableName { get; set; }
    public string RefTypeSchema { get; set; }
    public string RefTypeTableName { get; set; }
    public string Class1ColumnName { get; set; }
    public string Class2ColumnName { get; set; }
}
```